# Cannot save chat messages from Elixir to PostgreSQL

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I can't seem to persist any messages onto the database when reloading.

It doesn't show any error messages whatsoever.

Links added for the code.

room_channel.ex

```
defmodule Chat.RoomChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel
  alias Chat.Presence
  alias Chat.Repo
  alias Chat.User
  alias Chat.Message

  def join("room", payload, socket) do
    if authorized?(payload) do
      send(self(), :after_join)
      {:ok, socket}
    else
      {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
    end
  end

  def handle_in("new_messages", payload, socket) do
    spawn(fn -> save_message(payload) end)
    user = Repo.get(User, socket.assigns.user_id)
    broadcast! socket, "new_messages", %{user: user.name, message: payload["message"]}
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
    Message.recent_messages()
    |> Enum.each(fn msg -> push(socket, "new_messages", format_msg(msg)) end)
    user = Repo.get(User, socket.assigns.user_id)
    {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, user.name, %{
      online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
      })
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  defp format_msg(msg) do
    %{
      name: msg.name,
      message: msg.message
    }
  end

  defp save_message(message) do
    Message.changeset(%Message{}, message) |> Repo.insert
  end

  defp authorized?(_payload) do
    true
  end
end
```

message.ex

```rb
defmodule Chat.Message do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "messages" do
    field :name, :string
    field :message, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :message])
    |> validate_required([:name, :message])
  end

  def recent_messages(limit \\ 10) do
    Chat.Repo.all(Chat.Message, limit: limit)
  end
end
```

mix.exs

```rb
defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.5"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:coherence, "~> 0.3"}]
end
```

```
Elixir 1.11.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 23)
postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.0
```

I think the issue is on the handle_in function in room_channel.ex

```
spawn(fn -> save_message(payload) end)
```

Any clues for pointing in the right direction?

Comment: what happens if you save the message synchronously, by removing the `spawn` and do just `save_message(payload)` ?

also, you may want to handle invalid changesets in your `save_message` function -- check to see if the changeset is valid before attempting insertion.

Comment: Nothing changes using only `save_message(payload)`.

Comment: consider posting code, directly to your question, not via external links

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `message["message"]` to changeset  in your `save_message` function?

Comment: @EvaldoBratti if I do that it'll raise an error. `** (Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map, got: "testing123"`

Comment: Consider writing some tests for your `save_message/1` function to assert that it is working as expected (you may need to make the function public to do this).

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help. But I have solved my issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `%{name: user.name, message: payload["message"]})` in spawn on handle_in function. Since the map for payload was `%{user: user.name, message: payload["message"]})` which didn't seem to work.

```
def handle_in("message:new", payload, socket) do
  user = Repo.get(User, socket.assigns.user_id)
  spawn(fn -> save_message(%{name: user.name, message: payload["message"]}) end)
  broadcast! socket, "message:new", %{user: user.name, message: payload["message"]}
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

But then after refreshing, it still fetched the users as 'undefined'. Setting the following format_message function fixed that issue.

```
defp format_msg(msg) do
 %{
    user: msg.name,
    message: msg.message
  }
end
```